# How can I get my game progress back?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4, the-witcher-3

I deleted the game applications for Fallout 4 and The Witcher 3 to conserve memory.

Then, upon re-downloading the games, I was not able to locate my previous saved games. I still had all my trophies. The account I am using is a default account to my other account that has PlayStation Plus.

Did I simply screw up? Is there a way to recover? So much progress lost...

Comment: Which game are you playing? Fallout or Witcher?

Comment: Do you have Playstation Plus? If you do, you'd have access to the cloud saves

Comment: Both. I've made this mistake by deleting only the application to have memory to download more games. Once I downloaded the games my saved progress was gone but I still had all my trophies(sn).

Comment: The account I am using is a default account to my other account that has PlayStation Plus

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I don't have a PS4, but that seems really odd that it would delete your saved games as well. When people ask for clarification, it's good to put the extra information in the question. Others may wonder the same thing, comments get deleted, and you only get votes based on what's in the question. I added it in for you as an example.